# How to map on a inner Functor (ValidationNel[A, Option[B]])

Tags: scala, functor, scalaz

I need a combinator to convert a `ValidationNel[A, Option[B]]` into a `ValidationNel[A, Option[C]]` to map (by map the option) on the success of the validation.

Here is the code :

```
  def mapmap[A, B, C](valid: ValidationNel[A, Option[B]], f: B => C) : ValidationNel[A, Option[C]] =
    valid.map(_.map(f))
```

I've also tried to compose functor (but unfortunately, that do not compile) :

```
def nestedMap[A, B, C](valid: ValidationNel[A, Option[B]])(f: B => C) : ValidationNel[A, Option[C]] = {
  val composed = Functor[Validation].compose[Option]
  composed.map(valid, f)
}
```

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a *type lambda* to retrieve the `Functor` instance for `Validation`.

Here is the code :

```
def nestedMap[A, B, C](valid: ValidationNel[A, Option[B]])(f: B => C) : ValidationNel[A, Option[C]] = {
  val composed = Functor[({type l[a] = ValidationNel[A, a]})#l].compose[Option]
  composed.map(valid)(f)
}
```